# Zebra printer printing extra labels

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I am using ZPL to print from a Zebra printer (QLN420 model)

Label size is 4" wide and 2" inches length

But when I send a job for an image that is 4 x 2 to print, it prints 3 labels, first 2 are empty and last one gets the image

When I send a job for an image that is 4x6 it print correctly on 3 labels of 4x2

The printer is set to stop by mark, meaning it stops with a black mark on the back of the label. When pressing on the printer **feed** it prints only 1 4x2 but when printing with ZPL it prints 3 (2 empty and then the image

I tried using ^LL and set it manually but it didn't help

(I am using C# create the ZPL and to send to the printer)

Comment: Can you post the ZPL?  Not easy to debug without it.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to remove the `^MN` command.  That is ideally a setting that should be configured by the user when new labels are loaded i.e. when label breaks potentially change.  If you think about what it means to change the media tracking parameters, the printer may want to run a few blank labels to "resync" with the top of label.  Maybe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was to recalibrate the printer using this command:

```
! U1 setvar "media.type" "label"
! U1 setvar "media.sense_mode" "bar"
~jc^xa^jus^xz
```

Read more on the command here: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Calibrating-Zebra-QLn-Series-Mobile-Printers?language=en_US